# Supply a list of default values if list is empty in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm parsing command line arguments to determine which value I want my program to return

But if I supply no values, I want to add a bunch of default values to the list.

Kind of exactly like Python's `xs = parsed_list or [1,2,3]`

Comment: What's wrong with `let xs = if null parsed_list then [1, 2, 3] else parsed_list`?

Comment: If you want a similar presentation, just create a function : `nullOr [] d = d; nullOr xs _ = xs`. You can even use it infix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using guards:

```
xs | null parsed_list = [1,2,3]
   | otherwise        = parser_list
```

Using `if`: (as @Mephy suggested)

```
xs = if null parsed_list then [1,2,3] else parsed_list
```

Using pattern matching: (see @jtobin's answer)

Using `foldr` (not recommended):

```
xs = foldr (\_ _ -> parsed_list) [1,2,3] parsed_list
```

Using a custom operator:

```
ifEmpty :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
ifEmpty [] def = def
ifEmpty ys _   = ys

xs = parsed_list `ifEmpty` [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check and see if the parsed argument list is empty and supply the defaults if so.  Ex:

```
import System.Environment

defaults = undefined

foo = do
  args <- getArgs
  return $ case args of
    [] -> defaults
    xs -> xs
```